# How do I make a variable non-static without getting object reference error? (Beginner coder)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The update method in enemyHealth wants me to make targetHealth a static but if I do that then I won't be able to make unique enemies.

```
{
    public Text enemyHealth;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        enemyHealth.text = EnemyVitals.targetHealth.ToString();
    }
}
```

```
{
    public double targetHealth = 100;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (targetHealth <= 1)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *The update method in enemyHealth wants me* what?

Answer (score 1):

as far as I understand, this: `enemyHealth.text = EnemyVitals.targetHealth.ToString();`
tries to access targetHealth like you would access static classes for example `Vector3.up`. These static classes/methods allow you to use their methods without making an instance of that class. So in your case, you would need a reference to an EnemyVitals instance and call `.targetHealth` on that instance. You can for example instantiate one via `EnemyVitals enemyVit = new EnemyVitals();` or declare a public field in your first class like so: `public EnemyVitals enemyVit;`, then in the editor drag and drop the EnemyVitals reference to that field. I think you might rather want to get the reference somehow otherwise in-game, for example with raycasting to possible enemy objects etc..
From what you posted it seems to me that the latter is more what you would want to go for.